# call_user_func executes the function without executing __construct

Tags: php

I execute following class from my dispatcher class but neither class_exists nor  call_user_func execute the class, the __controller never runs. The session doesn't start.
At the moment as work around I am adding `$i = new Admin();` before the class deceleration so the class get's activated when the page is loaded. 
But this behavior seam odd to me.

Extract from dispatcher class:

```
        include $this->file;

        if (class_exists($this->controller, TRUE)) {

            if (!is_callable($this->controller, $this->action)) {
                header('Location: /404.php');
                exit;
            }
            call_user_func(array ($this->controller, $this->action), $this->route->values);
        }



<?php
class Admin
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        S::V()->title()->set('Admin');

        if (!isset($_SESSION))
            session_start();
        if (!isset($_SESSION['auth']))
            header('Location: /cp/login');      
    }

    public function lobby($args)
    {
        S::V()->title()->append(' Logger');
        if (isset($_REQUEST['clear'])) {
            S::L()->clear();
        }

        $data['raw'] = S::Logger()->gethtml('20');
        S::V()->addData($data);
        echo S::V()->fetch('admin.php', $data);
    }
?>
```

Comment: I did get it to work by executing the controller in the dispatcher first, and passing the object to the call_user_func rather then just the name. But I still think the class function lobby, which is not even a static function should have never gotten executed without the class being active. This must be a bug or something.

Comment: Feature! Calling a non-static method by name classname::method() should generate a E_STRICT level warning. It will be executed anyway. Welcome to PHP ;)

Comment: madflow: Actually I am not calling static, S is my Singleton class. See here: https://github.com/robotamer/Facade/blob/master/Facade/Singleton.php

Comment: I was reffering to your comment on the non-static Admin::hobby method.